How to create an alert (notification) if Azure web app health check is unhealthy
My ASP.NET Core web app (C#) running as an Azure app service (Linux) has a health check endpoint (/health) with custom health checks. E.g. DB connectivity, Graph API connectivity. The health check is configured in monitoring and shows as healthy. There is only single instance of the app.
I want to create a notification (preferably email) when the health check is unhealthy. E.g. The Client Secret expires. Ideally I don't want to have to write code to periodically call the health check and send an email.
In Alerts then I try and create an alert rule and the only signals with "health" don't seem suitable:

"Resource health" - Presumably not the same thing as a health check.
"Health check status" (Platform metrics) - Only has Count/Min/Max/Average options.


You can create availability tests and alerts in app insights: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/availability?tabs=standard.

Have you enabled Health check for an app service.

My first paragraph clearly states that the health check is enabled and is running. I just want to create a notification when it becomes unhealthy because it likely needs manual intervention rather than just recycling the app service.

Is KQL query approach works for you? @ChrisFellows

Yes, KQL query would work as long as I can get Azure to notify a user within minutes of the health check being unhealthy. I've looked but I can't see which table to query.


How to create an alert (notification) if Azure web app health check is unhealthy:-

After exploring information on your requirement, I found below approaches which satisfies it further.
Firstly, to check unhealthy instances from an Azure app service, you can set the Load balancing threshold to the specific time limit as shown below. After the given time, the app service consider the instances as unhealthy and remove it from the load balancer.
Also, you can save all the unhealthy instances information into a storage account by enabling Diagnostic collection in the below way and dedicate a specific storage account for the collection.

Once it's done, you can be able to view the detailed information in a folder called memory dumps in the specific blob container. In this way, you will be able to find the unhealthy instances details.


Coming to the alert rule, there are two approaches. One is, go to an app service >> Metrics >> Select Health Check Status and then click on create new alert rule. Then the below screen appears. Now you can simply add the threshold time as provided in the Load balancing limit.
It means the instances after reaching the specific load balancing threshold will be considering as unhealthy and triggers an email further.


Second approach is executing the KQL query on Log analytics workspace in Azure. You can use AppServiceHTTPLogs table as it contains logs for HTTP requests made to your app service.  Add the ScStatus field and User Agent field in the below format.
AppServiceHTTPLogs
| where ScStatus != 200 and UserAgent has "HealthCheck"
| project ScStatus, UserAgent, TimeGenerated, Result


Once it is executed, click on New Alert Rule and proceed further by adding the Email and action group details.


I don't understand what filter criteria needs to be set if I set up an alert rule on the "Health check status" metric. I don't understand what the Threshold Value is. There is only one app instance because I don't need load balancing. I just want an alert when the health check is unhealthy.
The AppServiceHTTPLogs table is empty for the last 7 days. The health check was enabled within the last 24 hours (The app service health check status also showed Healthy when it was running) and I can see data in the Azure charts for the "Health check status" metric.


Can you check the AppServiceHTTPLogs table for last 24 hrs? @ChrisFellows

The diagnostic setting for the app service is Categories="HTTP logs" & "App Service*" saved to Log Analytics workspace. AppServiceHTTPLogs contains entries for my page requests (including when I call /health) but there aren't any /health entries from monitoring. Possibly monitoring requests are treated as an internal request and don't get logged. The other AppService* tables are empty.

Is the issue resolved for you! @ChrisFellows
